# navigation bar expandable list view android

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview, navigation-drawer

I've been trying to recreate a navigation drawer looking something like this:

http://developer.android.com/design/media/navigation_drawer_holo_dark_light.png

It appears to just be an expandable list view within a navigation drawer but the trouble is I'm a bit of a newbie so i'm not sure on how to do it, any advice on how I would go about creating something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this tutorial, you'll learn as well.

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

As for the Navigation Drawer implementation, use a [Menu Drawer library](http://simonvt.github.io/android-menudrawer/), it will make it much easier.